# I cant get into my Ubuntu 14.04 server running in virtualbox via SSH from teraterm

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I am using bridged network connection for the virtualbox server. The interface 
eth0 doesnt have IP and the IP shown at virbr0 is out of my host network. I cant even ping from my PC running windows 8 into the virbr0 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it working after  NAT.
Use Host IP as 127.0.1.1 port 22
Guest IP as the eth0 IP port 22